# Flutter permission_handler re-request permissions

Tags: flutter

Currently, I have a simple method that requests location permissions in my app using permission_handler. Everything works well the 1st time around when accepting/denying permissions. However, once the 1st dialog gets a response, calling .request() no longer opens the permissions request dialog.

Is there a way to trigger the dialog within the app after the user has already responded?

Here's my method:

```
Future<bool> requestLocationPermissions() async {
    bool permissions = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request().isGranted;

    if (permissions) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```